# entry() get into the different address from the entry point I set in the Elf

Tags: operating-system, elf, osdev

Recently I'm learning about the OS. And I want to write a simple bootloader, which change the real mode to protect mode and then load the simple kernel.
But I can't figure out the entry address problem.
At first I put the bootloader in the first sector of the OS.img(qemu), and then the kernel begin at the second sector.
Here's readelf result of my kernel:
[image]
The entry point address is 0x800c.
And the LMA and VMA are below:
[image]
A part of the bootloader which read elf-type kernel and then get into the entry(),which is the entry point address.
[image]
However, when I disassemble the bootloader, the entry() is below:
[image]
Call *0x8018, not *0x800c.
I don't know why this happen.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Please provide text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call *0x8018` performs a call to an address that is stored at `0x8018`, that's correct since `ELFHDR` is `0x8000` and offset of `e_entry` in the header is `0x18`.

The real problem is in the way you load segments into memory. Each segment should be loaded at address `p_vaddr` from file offset `p_offset`. Notice that in your case `p_vaddr` is `0x8000`, that the same place in memory you loaded elf header to and that's why `ELFHDR->e_entry` gets overwritten. The easiest solution would be to load elf header at different address.

Source: http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Comment: There is no problem with the bootloader asm code. It is generated correctly. Like I said, value of `ELFHDR->e_entry` is stored at address `0x8018`. That's why there is a call to the function which address is stored at `0x8018`, that's what `call *0x8018` do. (Notice, that it is `call *0x8018`, not `call 0x8018`).